# How to get the driver for Realtek rtl8821ce onto a usb boot stick?

Tags: drivers, usb, realtek

I'm stuck in a loop: I need the internet to get the driver I need, I can't get the driver I need because I don't have the internet I need

I bought a new HP 15s-er1004AU laptop, not top of the range, but OK.

I made a start up usb disk for Ubuntu 20.04 with Start-up Disk Creator.

I installed Ubu 20.04 on the new HP. All good, except, no driver for the wifi and no wired internet socket.

This installed the driver for Realtek  on my current Samsung (I think), although it does not have a Realtek wifi card:

> sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms

So my question:

> Is there some way to get the correct driver onto the boot stick??

(I ordered an external usb wifi. I hope it will arrive today, is recognized and I can proceed to update Ubuntu on the new laptop.)

I tried copying the .deb package onto the new laptop, but, instead of installing, I get 'pending'.

I tried again with dpkg -i in a terminal on the new laptop.

Then I see that gcc is not installed, make is not installed all kinds of other dependencies to get dkms installed.

/var/cache/apt/archives/ does not contain any rtl8821ce.deb files, although I installed the Ubuntu package on this computer, so I can't run them onto the new computer.

If I could get gcc onto the new computer, maybe I could proceed.

I have the other debian packages I need, dkms and rtl8821ce

Comment: I have no package /var/cache/apt/archives/rtl8821ce or similar. I have a package: linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-137-generic_4.15.0-137.141_amd64.deb This computer has Intel i5 processors, the new HP has AMD Ryzen R7, I don't know if they would be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, good news:

The delivery man just brought my external wifi, cost 75 RMB.

The first thing Ubuntu did was tell me to repair the things I tried to install.

Now the correct Ubuntu drivers for rtl8821ce wifi are installed, but something to do with the MOK password is not letting it work.

I'll fix that!